# Efficiently find users using $near and excluding those who have disliked the user

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Here is the assumed schema I think is the best to put into place

---

- Users

  - userId
  - first_name
  - age
  - gender
  - location (lat,lon)

---

- Matches

  - userId (voter)
  - like (vote)
  - liked_UserId

---

I know how to find users using the near parameter:

```
db.users.find({loc: {$near:[-180,40]}}).limit(3)
```

**BUT**

1) I'm trying to figure out the best and efficient way of finding users who are the closest and excluding users who have disliked this user. Should I make two query calls??? maybe a $where clause from the other collection somehow?

Edit: I'm thinking make one query to get all the users who have disliked this certain user, then add this array of users as part of a second query in the $nin...but will that be very slow if there are over 400,000 entries?

2) Does Tinder show the user of a profile of another user that disliked them?

Comment: MongoDB does not support relational queries. You cannot query two tables in single query. So, you will have to make two queries to find data from two tables.

Comment: If thats the case, then I might as well make one query to get all the users who have disliked this certain user, then add this array of users as part of a second query in the $nin parameter...but will that be very slow if there are over 400,000 entries? Is there a better way?

Comment: yes, correct!.
This is how we are using to query our database, but the only difference is that we are making $near query first and then making second query on $in of result of first query.
But you can fire any of the query first. That won't matter much.

And yes, this does slow down the process, but unfortunately, mongoDB does not give us provision to make relational queries.

Comment: The **"efficient"** way is therefore to **embed** the related data you need to query on within the main objects you are querying for. This is after all why you should be using MongoDB in the first place, since you realized that a "join" does not efficiently scale for you. Or simply use something relational instead.